# Is it bad to keep references to Core Data objects around?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is it bad practice to keep references to managed objects inside view controllers for their lifetime?

I'm relatively new to Core Data, and I've recently discovered that you can't mix managed objects from different context, e.g. you can't add objects to a relationship if they don't belong to your context.

For example, say we have a classic `Employee` entity and an `EmployeeDetailsViewController` which keeps a strong reference to an `Employee` object.

Should I be storing an ID of the employee instead of the `Employee` object? It seems that working with IDs instead of domain objects is rather inconvenient so I was wondering how it's usually done.

Comment: This is a complicated subject, with lots of solutions.  I think the safe answer is to keep `objectID`s, not objects.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this bad practice, in fact its fairly common (considering core data objects are turned into faults on low memory situations and when they are no longer being used). But the solution you adopt should really depend on the requirements of the project.

Comment: This might interest you [Managing Object Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/MO_Lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH31-SW1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Core Data!

First, you probably have too many `NSManagedObjectContext` instances in your application.  Your entire User Interface should be running off **ONE** context.  That will solve your relationship problems.

As for holding onto references, there is no issue with holding onto them *except* when there is a chance of deleting that object from another thread.  If you have a situation where you are deleting on background threads (from network operations for example) then you probably don't want to keep strong references to those objects as it can get you into a difficult situation.

> Is it a good idea to have a separate context for one kind of changes e.g. stuff coming from server, and another for e.g. user changes (made through the UI)? I'm working on an app with a "sync offline changes" kind of feature and trying to figure out how to track these two types of changes separately so that for example changes coming from server would be discarded if user modified the same object. (you can also take a look at my other question about sync) (what a lengthy comment!)

So the rule that I live by:

- If UI; main queue context.  No exceptions
- If not UI; private queue context. No exceptions

I generally have my private queue contexts as children of the main queue context to reduce the amount of code and merging I need to deal with.

Your server syncing is therefore NOT UI and should be run against a private child context.

Watch my talk on [MVC-N](https://realm.io/news/slug-marcus-zarra-exploring-mvcn-swift/) for a deeper discussion.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have a separate context for one kind of changes e.g. stuff coming from server, and another for e.g. user changes (made through the UI)? I'm working on an app with a "sync offline changes" kind of feature and trying to figure out how to track these two types of changes separately so that for example changes coming from server would be discarded if user modified the same object. (you can also take a look at my other question about sync) (what a lengthy comment!)

Comment: Simple answer to your lengthy question update in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As you don't forget that you've stored your object, it's ok.
I do like this in most of my apps. I've got a main user selected at start then saved inside the rootController to avoid too much calls to CoreData as it won't change during use of the program.

If the entity change inside the app, you'll need to update the saved object from CoreData.

Comment: The last statement is irrelevant.  It's naturally less efficient if you have to keep re-faulting the object, but once loaded, you're using standard properties, and you don't get direct variable access to core data properties.